# Column style ignored using spreadsheets.batchUpdate with AppendCellsRequest

Tags: google-sheets-api

As a developer i use this endpoint: https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/reference/rest/v4/spreadsheets/batchUpdate

And request: 
https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/reference/rest/v4/spreadsheets/request#AppendCellsRequest
to insert new row with values.

I have spreadsheet with some column format styles: background-color/font-weight/text-wrap/data-validation.

[image: For example:]

The problem, when i use requests like this:

```
curl --request POST \
 'https://sheets.googleapis.com/v4/spreadsheets/1SoDx8YRyiKF9vKfa_2w0xc7DTNIlQoLC6hBq1SCJEJY:batchUpdate?key=[YOUR_API_KEY]' \
  --header 'Authorization: Bearer [YOUR_ACCESS_TOKEN]' \
  --header 'Accept: application/json' \
  --header 'Content-Type: application/json' \
  --data '{"requests":[{"appendCells":{"sheetId":0,"fields":"*","rows":[{"values":[{"userEnteredValue":{"stringValue":"TEST STRING VALUE long"}},{"userEnteredValue":{"stringValue":"TEST TEXT LONG"}}]}]}}]}' \
  --compressed
```

I see that text-wrap and data-validation styles are ignored:

[image]

Key point here that i use only: 'userEnteredValue' field to provide values.

According to the doc:
https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/reference/rest/v4/spreadsheets/cells#CellData
i can use 'userEnteredFormat'/'dataValidation', but "When writing, the new format will be merged with the existing format." I find it quite complicated to obtain and post those style formats once again.

My question - is there any way to just post CellData using AppendCellsRequest as simple as possible and preserve existing column styles?

Comment: I apologize for my poor English skill. Unfortunately, I cannot understand about `I see that text-wrap and data-validation styles are ignored:` from your image. Can I ask you about the detail of it?

Comment: Hi! Updated my description. As you can see validation 'warning' is missed for the first column, and text-wrapping is ignored for both columns

Comment: Thank you for replying and adding the information. From your additional information, I proposed a modification point as an answer. Could you please confirm it? If I misunderstood your issue and that was not the result you want, I apologize.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- You want to put the values using the AppendCellsRequest of batchUpdate method in Sheets API.
- You want to keep the text style and data validation rules of the cells when the AppendCellsRequest is run.
- You want to put only the text values.
- You have already been able to get and put values for Google Spreadsheet using Sheets API.

#### Modification point:

In your case, you use `"fields":"*"` while you set only the property of `userEnteredValue`. In this case, the properties except for `userEnteredValue` are also set. I think that this is the reason of your issue.

In order to avoid this issue, please use `userEnteredValue` to `fields`.

#### Modified request body:

When your request body is modified, it becomes as follows.

From:

```
--data '{"requests":[{"appendCells":{"sheetId":0,"fields":"*","rows":[{"values":[{"userEnteredValue":{"stringValue":"TEST STRING VALUE long"}},{"userEnteredValue":{"stringValue":"TEST TEXT LONG"}}]}]}}]}'
```

To:

```
--data '{"requests":[{"appendCells":{"sheetId":0,"fields":"userEnteredValue","rows":[{"values":[{"userEnteredValue":{"stringValue":"TEST STRING VALUE long"}},{"userEnteredValue":{"stringValue":"TEST TEXT LONG"}}]}]}}]}'
```

- `"fields":"*"` was modified to `"fields":"userEnteredValue"`.

#### References:

- [Method: spreadsheets.batchUpdate](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/reference/rest/v4/spreadsheets/batchUpdate)
- [AppendCellsRequest](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/reference/rest/v4/spreadsheets/request#appendcellsrequest)

Answer (score 0):

Tanaike's answer is correct, but I find the following strangeness.

My `CellData` looks like (Kotlin):

```
        fun cellDataDouble(value: Double, doublePattern: String = "#.#"): CellData {
            return CellData().also { cd ->
                cd.userEnteredFormat = CellFormat().setNumberFormat(NumberFormat().also { nf ->
                    nf.type = "Number"
                    nf.pattern = doublePattern
                })
                cd.userEnteredValue = ExtendedValue().setNumberValue(value)
            }
        }
```

so it seemed logical to me to set `fields` to `"userEnteredValue,userEnteredFormat"`, but if you do that other formatting in a column is erased. The behaviour is the same as `fields="*"`. This is shown in the test case screenshot below:
[image]

Line 20 was appended with the two fields specified, and line 21 with only `userEnteredValue`, which shows the the `userEnteredFormat` was not applied. The docs suggest formatting should be merged, but it is clear that the font and bold formatting is removed by just specifying the number format.